# Preferred way to terminate `ssh -N` in background using bash?

Tags: bash, ssh, background, terminate, portforwarding

I've started `ssh -N <somehost> &` in a bash script (to create a tunnel), and the connection persists after the script ends, and I see with `ps` that the ssh process has detached.

I am currently killing the background job with `kill jobs -p`, but is there a better way to do that?

Comment: This might be better suited to ServerFault or SuperUser

Comment: You can save the PID of the most recent background command: `pid=$!` and use it in a trap to kill the process as suggested by Pierre.

Answer (score 1):

Do you manually end your script?
if so:
     Try to catch the QUIT signal (or others) inside your script (use the 
 trap builtin command I think). Then kill ssh.

else:
     Kill ssh at the end of your script.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I don't see how this is better than using `kill jobs-p`.